# How to run Liquibase on jar execution using Maven?

Tags: liquibase, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I have a Maven project with Liquibase that I want to run by executing the jar file. Currently, I can only make it work during the build phase using version 3.10.3 of the Liquibase Maven plugin. I tried using newer versions of the plugin, but I couldn't make it work.

Here's my current pom.xml file:

```xml
<project>
  <!-- project details -->
  
  <properties>
    <liquibase.propertyFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</liquibase.propertyFile>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- dependencies -->
  </dependencies>
    
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- assembly plugin details -->
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <propertyFile>${liquibase.propertyFile}</propertyFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

How can I make Liquibase work when I execute the jar file instead of during the build phase? And is there a way to make it work with newer versions of the Liquibase Maven plugin?

I believe it can be done using exec-maven-plugin, but so far I haven't been able to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was using the liquibase-maven-plugin plugin. You only need to use the core of Liquibase in the dependencies section and manage the updates defined in db.changelog.xml programmatically using the APIs provided by Liquibase.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Database database;
    try {


        String url = getLiquibasePropertiesInfo().getUrl();
        String username = getLiquibasePropertiesInfo().getUsername();
        String password = getLiquibasePropertiesInfo().getPassword();
        String driver = getLiquibasePropertiesInfo().getDriver();
        String changeLogFile = getLiquibasePropertiesInfo().getChangeLogFile();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
            Class.forName(driver);
            // Create the Liquibase instance and update the database
            database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLogFile, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.update("");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```